# Why does Ukranian "х" correspond English "r"?

Tags: from-english

Why does Ukranian "х" correspond English "r"?
ea**r** ву**х**о
sea**r** су**х**ий
aldo**r** віль**х**а
thei**r** ти**х**
dee**r** ду**х**?

Comment: Please try elaborating your questions. [Your previous question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6393/8) has received several answers, and any answer to this question would essentially copy ideas from answers there. Should you expect for anything else, please express it in your question first.

Comment: Actually `deer` is `олень`.

Comment: @vovchisko compare Latin anima (breath) vs animal (animal)

Comment: This kind of silly based on nothing similar spam questions should be illegal.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such a correspondence in the two languages.

There are hundreds of words ending with 'r' in English, which do not have 'х' in Ukrainian. For example:

driver - водій

teacher - вчитель

far - далеко

for - для

four - чотири

beer - пиво

bear - ведмідь

and so on...

Comment: It may appear to be not so simple. I don't know where Jack gets such pairs of words, but, in [question #6393](/q/6393), it looked for many of us that there's no regularity, but, when we dived deeper, it appeared that the words (despite not being exact translations) are really cognates and the regularities exist; the same may appear here. (The difference between word pairs you specify and word pairs Jack specifies is that his word pairs are really cognates, for example both ear and вухо are from PIE *h₂ṓws, sear and сухий ← *h₂sews-, deer and дух ← *dʰews- (*dʰwes-).)

Comment: @Sasha Absolutely agree. But it appears that the author asked about common tendency.

Comment: @Sasha  One of this feature is Rhotacism

Comment: It's like asking "Why `delivery` word sounds like `removing a liver from its place`" ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Rhotacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism_(sound_change)) + [iurk rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruki_sound_law) ([Pedersen's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedersen%27s_law))

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.

Comment: Thanks! It's sad that such answers (laconic but very informative) get negative reaction just due to their form. (It would be nice if you could extend it a bit, but I personally appreciate it very much in any case.)